# Password change to SQL user and SQL Agent user broke mail agent

Tags: email, sql-server

We changed the passwords on the accounts which the SQL Server service and the SQL Server Agent use to log in. Both seem to be mostly working fine, however the mail agent is now having problems. It is able to send plain text mail, but when when a `@query` argument is provided (to `sp_send_dbmail`), the email never gets sent and no errors seem to be recorded. To be clear, before the password change `@query` arguments were working fine.

Also, in addition, it seems that the mail agent shuts down periodically now and I need to manually restart it with `msdb.dbo.sysmail_start_sp`. This also never occurred before the password change.

I suspect I am in a situation somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112849/sp-send-dbmail-executed-from-job-fails-with-query-result-attached-as-file) question. However, the "answer" to that question was simply to run as sa rather than fix the underlying problem. I'd like to actually understand what the issue is and fix it rather than employing an ugly workaround everywhere we need to call `sp_send_dbmail`.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Did you stop and restart both services after making the password change?

Comment: Yes, we did do that.